# Azure Resource Manager API to set tags on subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is there any APIs in the .net SDK that will allow me to set a tag on a subscription? The ISubscriptionOperations interface does not have any update methods.

Someone mentioned to me about using tag policies, but i could not find anything about that either.

Comment: Are you asking to apply a tag to the subscription itself or any/all resources within the subscription?

Comment: Both i guess. If we can't apply a tag to a subscription, it would be useful to have a tag automatically applied to all resources in a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Subscription objects are not taggable. So you cannot do that.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought someone mentioned it could be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically apply tags to the  resources or resource groups created within the subscription after a policy is created. You can set a policy on the resources within a *subscription scope* or limit the policy to a *resource group scope*.

Using the Azure Portal, navigate to **Policy** and then select **Definitions**. There are several definitions so filtering on 'append tag' will narrow down to what you seek. From my experience, you need to create one for 'resources' and another for 'resource groups'.

It is also possible to setup by PowerShell command (see MS link below) but I haven't worked with that yet.

[image]

Link to Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/enforce-tag-value